# Angular 8 Auto Reload redirects from google firebase reset password link to sign-in

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular-ui-router, router

I have deployed an angular 8 project that I created a custom Password reset link and component for but for some reason whenever the link is clicked the browser directs to that link and while project loading it auto refreshes link/ route and takes me to sign in instead.

I have tried

- Removing all router guards
- Adding object onSameUrlNavigationReload

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow but in order to find quality help you will need to provide more information than that, possibly even some code snippets. Please visit this link for more information `https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask`

Comment: This happen you in local ? , you can test it in local, just change custom URI to point localhost:4200

Comment: Yes this happens local as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check this 2 possible cases:

1. Thoroughly verify that the route you are opening exists in your routing file & there is no typo. If the route does not exist add it.
2. If the route exists then verify the routing sequence of the placed routes if you have "**" route mapped to SignIn page & the routes you are opening gets matched with this first then you will be redirected ti sign in page

Comment: Thanks for your response. So even if I just refresh clients it navigates back to sign in.

Comment: Can you share a stackblitz link with a sample code where i can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Found the issue! Appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was found in the NGXS router plugin and the package needed to be updated